# Tags com acentos

Tags: bug, status-pronto, acentuação

O site não aceita tags com acento. Por exemplo, ao digitar a tag `acentuação`, o resultado são duas tags: `acentua` e `o`.

Comment: Não entendi por que o problema não aconteceu nesta pergunta, mas ele ocorreu em http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/17/urls-com-acentos

Comment: Engraçado que todas as propostas em outras línguas da Area51 estão com o aviso "Allowing international characters in tags is our first priority before launch". Agora que o primeiro site foi lançado, justamente isso não funciona...

Comment: Screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pSEb2.png. No modo de edição vemos duas tags, mas na visualização aparece como uma só.

Comment: Dá para perceber que ocorre vários erros diferentes e até aceita alguns acentos.

Comment: Tive o mesmo problema. Utilizei a tag "localização" em uma pergunta, mas a tag foi mostrada como "localizacão" na página de perguntas. Ao editar pra tentar corrigir (imaginando que havia sido erro meu), apareceram duas tags: "localizac" e "o".

Comment: Para ajudar, a **edição quebra** mais ainda o acento (mesmo os que foram aceitos (por alguma razão alguns são aceitos) colocando #XXX no lugar do caractere acentuado e separando o final da tag em outra tag. Veja http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localizac%23227 e http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/o

Comment: Reparei que acentos funcionam, mas cedilha não: a tag `computação` vira `computacão`.

Comment: Essa pergunta/observação poderia ficar com mais votos...

Comment: @Gabe Dá para responder a esta pergunta de alguma forma, no sentido do autor poder marcar o assunto como "resolvido"? Dado tratar-se de uma questão de _DEV_, ideal seria seres tu ou outro diamante a responder dando conta que foi resolvido e agora aceita X Y e Z :)

Comment: @Zuul Eu testei (mais ou menos) agora pouco, e acho que tudo funciona agora. Vou ver com os devs se tem alguma coisa ainda quebrada

Comment: @Gabe Ok, pelo que temos testado tudo parece estar bem, é só mesmo responder a esta pergunta para ter uma resposta que possa ser marcada como "correta" e fechar o assunto!

Comment: @Zuul acho que o [meta-tag:status-pronto] é a melhor forma. Nem sei se o rodrigorgs está fazendo qualquer coisa no site para aceitar.

Comment: @bigown No caso particular deste autor sim, ele é activo :) Mas qualquer utilizador que se dá ao trabalho de vir aqui reportar um bug merece uma resposta de um diamante! :)