# Busca por tags com acentos não funciona quando "não" digitado o acento

Tags: bug, novo-recurso, status-aceito

> Note que está questão é diferente desta: [Tags com acentos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/18/3635)

Tentei procurar a tag [análise](/questions/tagged/an%c3%a1lise) ao criar uma pergunta digitando (sem acento):

> analise

No entanto não encontrei a tag, tive que digitar com o acento, não é um grande problema, mas isto me faz pensar que podemos ficar criando tags desnecessárias e depois teremos trabalho ao ter que ficar editando perguntas.

Não sei se isto é um problema da aplicação (tecnologia do site) ou o banco de dados que não suporta este tipo de consulta, mas acho que seria interessante (talvez apenas interessante para o StackOverflow em Português e pro Portuguese StackExchange)

Comment: Relacionado: [Quem procura, (agora) acha](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2382/91)

Comment: Hum.... bem lembrado. Vou dar uma olhada.